# Reflect Oriented and Aspect Oriented in .Net and C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, aspect

Does .Net framework and specially C# language supports `Reflect Oriented Programming` and `Aspect Oriented Programming`?

Comment: Yes for both, see System.Reflection namespace and http://www.sharpcrafters.com/aop.net

Comment: @jbl I'd say that C# doesn't support AOP. You need PostSharp or similar extensions, plain C# doesn't work well.

Comment: It also seems like Anders Hejlsberg is against AOP. http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Anders-Hejlsberg-Dead-Body.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes, .NET itself support AOP and Reflect Oriented Programming.

Reflect Oriented Programming using reflection and System.Reflection namespace.

For AOP there are multiple [ways](http://ayende.com/blog/2615/7-approaches-for-aop-in-net). And only remote proxies and deriving from ContextBoundObject are supported by .NET Framework itself, but not recommended to use for AOP due to their performance. All other possibilities using 3rd party libraries.

- Approach using Remoting Proxies
- Deriving from ContextBoundObject
- Compile-time subclassing (Rhino Proxy)
- Runtime subclassing( Castle Dynamic Proxy )
- Hooking into the profiler API( Type Mock )
- Compile time IL-weaving  ( Post Sharp / Cecil )
- Runtime IL-weaving ( Post Sharp / Cecil )

Answer (score 0):

Reflection, yes: you can use the System.Reflection namespace.

Aspect-oriented Programming is not really supported by .NET/C# as is, you'll need a third party tool for that. Some popular examples are PostSharp and Castle DynamicProxy.